# AngularJS Filter search with empty filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, filter

I have a problem.

I made a filter search, and when the input is dirty but empty, none elements show, I wanna show all when the filter is empty.

```
<div class="zc-select" target="SelectedCountry">
    <div class="principal-select" ng-click="openSelect($event)">
      <div ng-show="SelectedCountry.length === 0">
        Select a country
      </div>
      <div ng-show="SelectedCountry.length > 0">
        {{SelectedCountry[0].name}}
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="select-search">   
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      <input placeholder="Want to search?" max-length="44" only-text ng-model="countryFilter">
    </div>
    <ul class="select-elems">
      <li ng-repeat="i in countries | filter:countryFilter" select-id="{{i.id}}" ng-click="setSelect(i); profile_info.$dirty = true">{{i.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please, add the contents of `$scope.countries` to the question.

Comment: use `ng-change` to find if the input has been modified and then set a scope variable that makes the elements show.